# Manage storage of images in a Java web applicaition

Tags: java, image, jakarta-ee, local-storage

I'm working on a Java Enteprise web application that manages many image files.

I do not want to store the image files in a database.

Do I have to store the images on the filesystem?  Is there an established framework for this purpose?

To access to images to save on filesystem for to optimize the performance that you give me advice?

Comment: Is there a particolar reason for not using a DB?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the image management?  Are you managing a specific, limited set of images, or do the quantity of images grow?  Are you receiving new images all the time?  What type of images? Are you converting images from one format to another? Are you keeping track of meta data associated with the images?  Are you generating new images?  Are they saved on the local filesystem or do you have access to a larger storage array?

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on what you mean by "To access to images to save on filesystem for to optimize the performance that you give me advice?"

Comment: Even a database gets stored on a filesystem.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I have read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: @JoshDM The web application is like Flickr or 500px. So, upload of photographies, storage of original photos and thumbinals, storage in DB of metadata (data exif, etc). View of photo set.

Comment: @JoshDM for access on filesystem I have read of to use sendfile() system call. I wanted more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a filesystem for the image binary itself, and use a database table for all the ancillary metadata, including the filesystem path where the binary can be found.